# Migrating to Selenium 2

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-webdriver

Selenium 2/Webdriver has all sorts of great benefits but there is one big drawback: it doesn't support running on a grid out of the box.

Has anybody switched from using a SE1 grid to using SE2 serially and been satisfied with the results? I'm wondering if the benefits of SE2 make up for the expected loss of speed due to running serially. Is SE2 fast enough that it somewhat makes up for this disparity?

Alternatively, has anybody rolled their own parallelization framework for Selenium 2/Webdriver? It seems like it wouldn't be too difficult to create a primitive one that knows how to poll slave machines and distribute requests accordingly.

Comment: If  you use Java, you can use Gradle (or Maven) and use the parallel forking features of those frameworks.  Then, to control slave machines and schedule things, use a Jenkins server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Selenium 2 moves into beta we, the Core developers, will start looking into the integration with Grid. This should be happening by the end of the year.

It shouldnt be too difficult all that it needs to do is pass on the RemoteWebDriver commands and the browser capabilities from the hub onto the hub that has the browser.

Comment: Sounds like I'm just a bit early to the party then. I'd love to help out with this.